# Merge 2 tables into 1 SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my current table:

```
Sales Table
OrderID  Customer_ID  Customer_Name
 1         12            Bob
 2         18            Ben
 3         11            Harry
```

`OrderID` is the primary key

I have a temporary table `Temp1`:

```
Order_CreateDate   Order_ReturnDate
     20051102           20051104
     20051103           20051108
     20051104           20051105
```

I want to change the dates `YYYYMMDD` in `Temp1 table`, to `YYYY-MM-DD`, and move it to table, this code below does not work if I insert straight into `Sales Table` as it displays error saying:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Order_ID', table 'car_rental.dbo.DataInCentralDatabase2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

However if I test it out by outputting to another temporary table, `temp2`, it works.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[sales]([Order_CreateDate])
   SELECT
      CONVERT(date,Order_CreateDate,111) AS Order_CreateDate 
   FROM dbo.temp1
```

But running this code two times for `temp2 table` (for the two converted columns) has the following result:

```
Order_CreateDate   Order_ReturnDate
   2005-11-02          
   2005-11-03           
   2005-11-04          
    NULL             2005-11-04
    NULL             2005-11-08
    NULL             2005-11-05
```

I know this question is extremely confusing, but as the end result I want it to become like this:

```
OrderID  Customer_ID  Customer_Name    Order_CreateDate   Order_ReturnDate
 1         12            Bob              2005-11-02             2005-11-04
 2         18            Ben              2005-11-03             2005-11-08
 3         11            Harry            2005-11-04             2005-11-05
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: If you don't have orderID in your Temp1 table, how you can understand which date is for which order?

Comment: Does your temp table Temp1 has OrderID column also to map dates with corresponding orders?

Comment: I can recreate temptable1 to have OrderID as well with the CreateDate and ReturnDate, however how do I insert it into the main sales table so it becomes the end result posted?

Comment: if your "date" columns are in fact `DateTime`, then you dont need the convert statement when you insert.

Comment: does "DateTime" accept 20051104? Actually I want Date only

Comment: So, you're saying that the column type in your temp table for the "date" coluumns is a varchar?

Comment: CreateDate and ReturnDate are currently nvarchar, i recall selecting "Date" and "DateTime" while importing data from excel file, it showed up error saying something about not enough space or something

Comment: So you are saying you can add order id to your temp table?

Comment: these are all imports from an excel file, data and the column, so i can create another temp table and have Order_id with CreateDate and ReturnDate

Comment: Don't you mean you need to update the date columns? Inserting will add new rows with nulls for the columns you aren't inserting to. I think you need an update statement, and a way to map the dates to the existing rows. How do you currently know which date is for Bob?

Comment: The `DateTime` column holds all your date information.  Then when you want to select it, you can choose any format you want.  its always best to store date information as a DateTime column

Comment: this is what happens when I import from excel the column and data into a new table and choose "DATETIME":
Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "Order_CreateDate" (36) to column "Order_CreateDate" (136).  The conversion returned status value 6 and status text "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".

Comment: Quick question... what type is best for ID? Float? Int? Numeric?

Comment: @Tuzki Int from that three. Since it is a PK. I used this to help choose https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another column in Temp1 table as

```
    OrderID  Order_CreateDate   Order_ReturnDate
       1            20051102           20051104
       2            20051103           20051108
       3            20051104           20051105
```

Use Update query and not Insert query

```
UPDATE a set 
    Order_CreateDate=CONVERT(datetime,b.Order_CreateDate,111),
    Order_ReturnDate=CONVERT(datetime,b.Order_ReturnDate,111) 
from [dbo].[sales] a join [dbo].[Temp1] b on a.OrderID = b.OrderID
```

Comment: ill give that a try now

Answer (score 1):

At the first, you should get an updated version of temp1 like this:

```
 select 
      CONVERT(date,Order_CreateDate,111) as Order_CreateDate,
      CONVERT(date,Order_ReturnDate,111) as Order_ReturnDate,
      OrderID 
   into #temp2
 from temp1
```

then, update your main table with join on temp1, like this:

```
update s
   s.Order_CreateDate = t.Order_CreateDate,
   s.Order_ReturnDate = t.Order_ReturnDate
from sales s
        inner join #temp2 t
          on s.OrderID = t.OrderID
```